# How to render Here Maps (Javascript API) when there is an overlay

Tags: vuetify.js, here-api, heremaps

I want to display a dialog box hover a map. An overlay with opacity is hover the whole map (see the image below).

[image: here maps with overlay]

I successfully implemented the map without the dialog box and the overlay.
I can successfully call the dialog box after the map is rendered without any problem.

The issue is when I want to display the dialog and the overlay at the same time when the map is rendered for the first time. I get an empty map. Still, the markers and the here map logo are shown (see image below).

[image: here map empty with overlay]

- I tried to force reloading the base layer, without success.
- I tried to restart engine, without success.
- As I am using vuetify I tried to forceUpdate, without success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule we don't support an integration our HERE JS API with any JS framework.

Basically recommendation: Please don't use a map container (HTML element into which the map will be rendered) as part of Virtual DOM of some JS framework it will not work.